# F3 (Mission Control) key on MacOS with 2 displays. Sometimes it just opens Mission Control on one display but not on the other

Tags: macos, mission-control

When I use 2 displays on macOS sometimes my <kbd>F3</kbd> / "Mission Control" key just opens Mission Control on one display but not on the other.

I don't know where and how to change that setting again.

It just happens randomly from time to time.

How can I change that back and how does this happen?

Comment: Could you please share your Display preferences in Settings? Actually your problem is an answer to some question I couldn't be able to fulfill: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73104/multi-monitor-mac-possible-to-keep-one-screen-static-in-mission-control